# How to quickly assign a ctypes cast array without a for loop (in python)

Tags: python, arrays, memory-management, ctypes

I am interacting with a DAQ device which takes in a numerical dataset and outputs corresponding waveform.

Working part of the code is as follows:

```
#windows buffer allocation through 3rd part library. num_points is total length of 1D array
memhandle = ul.win_buf_alloc(num_points) 

#cast an array to take C ushort variables to allocated memory
data_array = ctypes.cast(memhandle, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ushort))  

#assign array with calculated signals
for i in range(0, num_points):
     data_array[i] = np.int(np.around(32768 + signals[i] * 3061.8)) 

#At last, 3rd party function to grab assigned values through memhandle and output
ul.a_out_scan(board_num, low_chan, high_chan, num_points, daq_rate, ul_range, memhandle, ScanOptions) 

# Free the buffer and set the data_array to None
ul.win_buf_free(memhandle)
data_array = None
```

In my case, the for loop range (or num_points) is very large (~1 million) and taking a few seconds to execute. Is it possible to pass the whole array at once without a for loop to make it faster?

I tried a few options but my limited understanding of ctypes, pointers and memory handling has kept me away from a solution.

Comment: what does *signals* hold, and also what kind of array is it?

Comment: _signals_ holds a simple floating point 1D array with its element values between +10 to -10. This is a python type. The length is not constant though as it changes based on user interaction in rest of the code. Length of this array could be anywhere between 10,000 to 1 million.  Towards 1 million points the code gets slow - 10+ seconds to execute

Answer (score 0):

To speed up the scaling use

```
data_array = np.around(32768 + signals * 3061.8).astype(np.ushort)
```

This creates a `ushort` array (check for overflow though).
Now that you have the data in the right format, you could probably pass the pointer to the array directly to your 3rd party function:

```
memhandle = data_array.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ushort))
```

If the 3rd party function really needs the specially allocated buffer, then copy the data over:

```
memhandle = ul.win_buf_alloc(num_points) 
ctypes.memmove(
    ctypes.cast(memhandle, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ushort)),
    data_array.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ushort)),
    data_array.size,
)
```